# HDFql Filling Dataset Iteratively from std::vector

Tags: hdf5, hdf, hdfql

I am trying to fill a dataset in an HDF5 file iteratively using HDFql. What I mean by iteratively, is that my simulator occasionally comes along with an update and I wish to dump some more data (which is contained in a `std::vector`) into my dataset. Weirdly though, something breaks after a few 'iterations' and my dataset begins to just fill with zeros.

Luckily, this error also occurs in a minimal example and seems to be reproducible with the below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <random>
#include <HDFql.hpp>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    HDFql::execute("CREATE TRUNCATE FILE /tmp/test_random.h5");
    HDFql::execute("USE FILE /tmp/test_random.h5");
    HDFql::execute("CREATE GROUP data");
    HDFql::execute("CREATE CHUNKED DATASET data/vals AS SMALLINT(UNLIMITED)");
    HDFql::execute("CLOSE FILE");
    std::stringstream ss;
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 eng(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist_vals(0, 500);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist_len(300, 1000);
    for(int i=0; i<500; i++)
    {
        const int num_values = dist_len(eng);
        std::vector<uint16_t> vals;
        for(int i=0; i<num_values; i++)
        {
            const int value = dist_vals(eng);
            vals.push_back(value);
        }
        HDFql::execute("USE FILE /tmp/test_random.h5");

        ss << "ALTER DIMENSION data/vals TO +" << vals.size();
        HDFql::execute(ss.str().c_str()); ss.str("");

        ss << "INSERT INTO data/vals(-" << vals.size() << ":1:1:" << vals.size() 
            << ") VALUES FROM MEMORY " 
            << HDFql::variableTransientRegister(vals.data());
        HDFql::execute(ss.str().c_str()); ss.str("");

        HDFql::execute("CLOSE FILE");
    }
}
```

This code runs for 500 'iterations', filling the data vector with a random amount of random data each time. In my latest run, everything beyond data cell 4065 in the final output hdf file was just zeros.

So my question is: what am I doing wrong here?
Many thanks!

### Edit

On further experimentation, I have come to the conclusion that this is possibly a bug in HDFql. Looking at the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <random>
#include <HDFql.hpp>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    HDFql::execute("CREATE TRUNCATE FILE /tmp/test_random.h5");
    HDFql::execute("USE FILE /tmp/test_random.h5");
    HDFql::execute("CREATE CHUNKED DATASET data/vals AS SMALLINT(0 TO UNLIMITED)");

    std::stringstream ss;
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 eng(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist_vals(0, 450);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist_len(100, 300);
    int total_added = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<5000; i++)
    {
        const int num_values = 1024; //dist_len(eng);
        std::vector<uint16_t> vals;
        for(int j=0; j<num_values; j++)
        {
            const int value = dist_vals(eng);
            vals.push_back(value);
        }

        long long dim=0;
        ss << "SHOW DIMENSION data/vals INTO MEMORY " << HDFql::variableTransientRegister(&dim);
        HDFql::execute(ss.str().c_str()); ss.str("");

        ss << "ALTER DIMENSION data/vals TO +" << vals.size();
        HDFql::execute(ss.str().c_str()); ss.str("");

        ss << "INSERT INTO data/vals(-" << vals.size() << ":1:1:" << vals.size()
            << ") VALUES FROM MEMORY "
            << HDFql::variableTransientRegister(vals.data());
        HDFql::execute(ss.str().c_str()); ss.str("");

        total_added += vals.size();
        std::cout << i << ": "<<  ss.str() << ":  dim = " << dim
                << " : added = " << vals.size() << " (total="
                << total_added << ")" << std::endl;

    }

    HDFql::execute("CLOSE FILE");
}
```

This code keeps the size of the data constant at 1024 (`num_values = 1024;`) and should work fine. However, if this is changed to 1025, the bug appears and is evidenced by the console outputting:

```
....
235: :  dim = 240875 : added = 1025 (total=241900)
236: :  dim = 241900 : added = 1025 (total=242925)
237: :  dim = 0 : added = 1025 (total=243950)
238: :  dim = 0 : added = 1025 (total=244975)
239: :  dim = 0 : added = 1025 (total=246000)
....
```

Indicating that something breaks at iteration 470, since the dimension of the dataset is clearly not zero.

Weirdly, this does not explain why I was having this problem in the original example, since the size of the data array was capped to 500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out where the problem is - in the following, the first example works and the second does not:

#### Works

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <random>
#include <HDFql.hpp>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int total_added = 0;
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 eng(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist_vals(0, 450);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist_len(100, 300);
    const int fixed_buffer_size = 10000;

    HDFql::execute("CREATE TRUNCATE FILE /tmp/test_random.h5");
    HDFql::execute("USE FILE /tmp/test_random.h5");
    HDFql::execute("CREATE CHUNKED DATASET data/vals AS INT(0 TO UNLIMITED)");

    for(int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    {
        const int num_values = dist_len(eng);
        std::vector<int> vals(fixed_buffer_size);
        long long dim = 0;
        sprintf(script, "SHOW DIMENSION data/vals INTO MEMORY %d", HDFql::variableTransientRegister(&dim));
        HDFql::execute(script);

        sprintf(script, "ALTER DIMENSION data/vals TO +%d", num_values);
        HDFql::execute(script);

        for(int j=0; j<num_values; j++)
        {
            const int value = dist_vals(eng);
            vals.at(j) = value;
        }
        sprintf(script, "INSERT INTO data/vals(-%d:1:1:%d) VALUES FROM MEMORY %d", num_values, num_values, HDFql::variableTransientRegister(vals.data()));
        HDFql::execute(script);
        HDFql::execute("FLUSH");

        total_added += num_values;
        std::cout << i << ": " << ":  dim = " << dim << " : added = " << num_values << " (total=" << total_added << ")" << std::endl;
    }

    HDFql::execute("CLOSE FILE");
}
```

#### Fails

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <random>
#include <HDFql.hpp>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int total_added = 0;
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 eng(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist_vals(0, 450);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist_len(100, 300);

    HDFql::execute("CREATE TRUNCATE FILE /tmp/test_random.h5");
    HDFql::execute("USE FILE /tmp/test_random.h5");
    HDFql::execute("CREATE CHUNKED DATASET data/vals AS INT(0 TO UNLIMITED)");

    for(int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    {
        const int num_values = dist_len(eng);
        std::vector<int> vals(num_values);
        long long dim = 0;
        sprintf(script, "SHOW DIMENSION data/vals INTO MEMORY %d", HDFql::variableTransientRegister(&dim));
        HDFql::execute(script);

        sprintf(script, "ALTER DIMENSION data/vals TO +%d", num_values);
        HDFql::execute(script);

        for(int j=0; j<num_values; j++)
        {
            const int value = dist_vals(eng);
            vals.at(j) = value;
        }
        sprintf(script, "INSERT INTO data/vals(-%d:1:1:%d) VALUES FROM MEMORY %d", num_values, num_values, HDFql::variableTransientRegister(vals.data()));
        HDFql::execute(script);
        HDFql::execute("FLUSH");

        total_added += num_values;
        std::cout << i << ": " << ":  dim = " << dim << " : added = " << num_values << " (total=" << total_added << ")" << std::endl;
    }

    HDFql::execute("CLOSE FILE");
}
```

The *only* difference between the two is that in the first the size of the data buffer `vals` is fixed and that in the second the data buffer size is created dynamically and randomly.

I don't understand why this error occurs, since in c++ `std::vector`s are [supposed](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/) to have the underlying data lie contiguous in memory and be fully compatible with C arrays and pointer magic. But clearly the compiler is doing something different in each example. Anyways, I hope this helps anyone else with this issue - the solution is to use fixed size data buffers.

Answer (score 1):

You are using variable `i` both in the outer and inner `for` loop, which is wrong. Also, as a suggestion, the code snippet you have posted could be optimized with the following:

1. No need to create group `data` as when you create the dataset `data/vals`, HDFql creates `data` as a group (if it does not exist) and `vals` as a dataset.
2. No need to open and close the file `/tmp/test_random.h5` inside the loop (as this has a performance penalty); just open the file in the beginning of your code and close it at the end of the code.

Here goes the code corrected/refactored:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <random>
#include <HDFql.hpp>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    HDFql::execute("CREATE TRUNCATE AND USE FILE /tmp/test_random.h5");

    HDFql::execute("CREATE CHUNKED DATASET data/vals AS SMALLINT(0 TO UNLIMITED)");

    std::stringstream ss;
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 eng(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist_vals(0, 500);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist_len(300, 1000);

    for(int i=0; i<500; i++)
    {
        const int num_values = dist_len(eng);
        std::vector<uint16_t> vals;
        for(int j=0; j<num_values; j++)
        {
            const int value = dist_vals(eng);
            vals.push_back(value);
        }

        ss.str("");
        ss << "ALTER DIMENSION data/vals TO +" << vals.size();
        HDFql::execute(ss);

        ss.str("");
        ss << "INSERT INTO data/vals[-" << vals.size() << ":1:1:" << vals.size() 
            << "] VALUES FROM MEMORY " 
            << HDFql::variableTransientRegister(vals);
        HDFql::execute(ss);

    }

    HDFql::execute("CLOSE FILE");

}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer - the index ``i`` is definitely a typo. However, this code gives me the exact same bug/error - at some places it simply fills the dataset with zeros (see the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WlWD.png).

Also, the reason I open/close the file on each iteration is to simulate my actual use-case, where I need to dump data into the HDF5 at random intervals.

Comment: Concerning opening/closing the file, it's probably better to flush (i.e. write) the data instead then by doing `HDFql::execute("FLUSH");`

Answer (score 1):

To reply to your edit above, there is no issues in extending the dimension of the dataset with `num_values` set to `1025`.

Here goes the code snippet that I used to test this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "HDFql.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char script[1024];
    int total_added = 0;
    int num_values = 1025;

    HDFql::execute("CREATE TRUNCATE AND USE FILE /tmp/test_random.h5");

    HDFql::execute("CREATE CHUNKED DATASET data/vals AS SMALLINT(0 TO UNLIMITED)");

    for(int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
    {
        long long dim = 0;
        sprintf(script, "SHOW DIMENSION data/vals INTO MEMORY %d", HDFql::variableTransientRegister(&dim));
        HDFql::execute(script);

        sprintf(script, "ALTER DIMENSION data/vals TO +%d", num_values);
        HDFql::execute(script);

        total_added += num_values;
        std::cout << i << ": " << ":  dim = " << dim << " : added = " << num_values << " (total=" << total_added << ")" << std::endl;
    }

    HDFql::execute("CLOSE FILE");

}
```

Comment: Sure, but in this example you are not actually writing any data into the dataset. The problem here occurs when data is written from a std::vector into the dataset as well. But this was helpful, since it indicates that the issue is not with expanding the dataset.